# find() not working using jQuery

Tags: jquery, find

I want to store `div.text` data in a variable and the show it in an alert box but my alert box is empty. [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRAN6/) or you can also see my code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="backToTop">
    <div class="abc">hi how r u
        <div class="text">i am fine an u </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="click">click</div>

</div>
```

**Jquery Script**

```
$(document).on('click','.backToTop',function(){

    var text = $(this).parent('.backToTop').find('.text').text();
    alert(text);

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `parent('.backToTop')` because you are already selected that , also there is not any other parent with that class

```
$(document).on('click','.backToTop',function(){
    var text = $(this).find('.text').text();
    alert(text);
})
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/uRAN6/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You were using wrong class-name. Try using this:

```
$(document).on('click','.click',function(){
var text = $(this).parent('.backToTop').find('.text').text();
alert(text);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding parents is unnecessary. Because looking for this element

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.backToTop',function(){

    var text = $(this).parent('.backToTop').find('.text').text();
    alert(text);

})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pesulap/uRAN6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).on('click','.backToTop',function(){

        var text = $(this).find('.text').text();
        alert(text);

        })
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRAN6/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
var text = $(this).parent('.backToTop').find('.text').text();
```

to this:

```
var text = $(this).find('.text').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

**this** is the `backToTop` element and you are getting the `this` as parent which is incorrect as you have no other parent element referring to `backToTop`.

Just use this:

```
var text = $(this).find('.text').text();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRAN6/6/)